# Error handling inside JSX map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a map function that is iterating through an array and populating a table like this:

```
var programData = this.state.data.map(program => (
  <tr >

    <td >
      {program.scheduledStartDateTime}
    </td>
    <td>
      {program.searchableTitles[1].value.en}
    </td>
  </tr>
));
```

However, sometimes the second field: `program.searchableTitles[1].value.en` is empty thus resulting in the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

How can I handle this exception? I've tried adding Try and Catch but I can't seem to find a way to make it work within JSX code.

I don't mind what goes into the field where there is no data present, it can be left empty.

Comment: {program.searchableTitles[1].value.en || ''} will this work?

Comment: @Pragun This will not work as `searchableTitles[1]` is already `undefined`.

Comment: @pragun nope it doesnt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way

```
var programData = this.state.data.map(program => (
  <tr>
    <td>
      {program.scheduledStartDateTime}
    </td>
    <td>
      {program.searchableTitles && program.searchableTitles[1] && program.searchableTitles[1].value.en}
    </td>
  </tr>
));
```

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted. It's basically the straight forward solution to OPs problem.

Comment: doesnt work: TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Comment: Well, I updated my answer. It's not nice but we can't know how deep your data can be missing

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the data through an API call then the data might not be immediately available or if you the state is not set immediately.

You can display different view instead

```
var programData = this.state.data.map(program => (
  <tr >

    <td >
      {program.scheduledStartDateTime}
    </td>
    <td>
{program.searchableTitles[1] ? 
     program.searchableTitles[1].value.en : <p> Not available </p> }
    </td>
  </tr>
));
```

Comment: `program.searchableTitles[1].value` in your condition gets the exact same error the user has. It should be `program.searchableTitles[1]`

Comment: this solution doesnt work but you might be right about it taking long for me to get the full response from the api. Is there a way which i can delay the render?